# How to get textBox value of View in Controller without using Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a View -

```
@Html.TextBox("Text1","", new { style = "width:350px;" })<br />
<input type="submit" value="Pay" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Pay", "Test")'" />
```

where `Pay` is my action result and `Test` is my controller.
I would like to have `Text1` value in controller.How can I achieve this with out using Form and not through ajax call?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without `Form` or without `java-script`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use javascript. Start by giving your textbox an unique identifier:

```
@Html.TextBox("Text1", "", new { id = "text1", style = "width:350px;" }
```

and then in the `onclick` handler you could pass the value entered in the textbox to the controller action:

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Pay", "Test")?text=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('text1').value);"
```

and now your `Pay` controller action might look like this:

```
public ActionResult Pay(string text)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: How it can be possible if I have more number of TextBoxes? And I am ok for using Form, but why its not getting fired?

Comment: @Darin, thanx for your support. I ended up by using Form.

Comment: @Sandy, if you have multiple textboxes you will have to append their values as query string parameters. Really, using a Form is the correct approach here.

Answer (score 1):

Controller expects HTTP verbs e.g. POST, GET, etc. POST requires a `<form />` while GET requires query string. You could use query string to pass your values

```
function sendValues()
{
   var value1 = document.getElementById('txtfirstname').value;
   var value2 = document.getElementById('txtlastname').value;

   var url = 'http://mysite.com/controllername/?firstname='+value1+'&lastname='+lastname;

   location.href = url;
}
```

However, I don't this it's ok to expose values in query string if they are sensitive

Answer (score 0):

It is possible  using either **Javascript/Jquery Ajax** or **Form**.